# How to apply a category's display setting to all categories?

Tags: admin, category

I have many categories and instead of applying new settings to all categories one by one, i would like to know if this is possible to apply new settings to all categories at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way of doing this from the UI.
The way I usually do it, is to update the values in the database. It's not the recommended approach but it works.
Let's say you want to update the `is_anchor` attribute to '1' for all categories.

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'is_anchor'
```

The query above should give you the `is_anchor` attribute. I the record that results I see that the attribute id is 51 (could be different for you). and the `backend_type` is `int`. This means that the values for the attribute are in the table `catalog_category_entity_int`.

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_entity_int` set value = 1 where attribute_id = 51 and parent_id <> 0;
```

This query will set the value 1 for the attribute is_anchor (id 51), for all the categories except the 'root of all roots', the category with `parent = 0`.
After I run the query, I reindex the flat categories and that's it.

Comment: perfecto! exactly what i was looking for :D

Comment: Updated SQL query for newer versions of Magento (I didn't have parent_id column for example).    UPDATE `catalog_category_entity_int` set value = 1 where attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` where attribute_code = 'is_anchor');

Comment: @Marius not work in my case i try UPDATE `catalog_category_int` set value = 1 where attribute_id = 51 and parent_id <> 0; but error:#1146 - Table 'magento1.catalog_category_int' doesn't exist

Comment: @Dinesh this means there is something wrong with your magento instance.

Comment: @Marius how to find & fix it, any help

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which settings you are changing in your category, but if it is on the list of options on [this page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.update.html), then using the Magento REST API is probably your best option.

Answer (score 1):

First identify the attribute id of the is_anchor attribute:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'is_anchor';
```

we Get attribute id 51 in my database. Now run the following query

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int set value = 1 where attribute_id = 51;
```

replace 51 with your own attribute id. And just rebuild these indexes